# Ruby class accessing protected method of child class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a background in Node Js and I am new to Ruby, Pardon me If this question is a noob.
I have 3 classes like this.

```
class Babylon::Metric::Counter < Babylon::Metric
  protected

  def record
    # some code here
  end
end
```

```
class Babylon::Metric::Gauge < Babylon::Metric
  protected

  def record
    # some code here
  end
end
```

and the parent class of these is

```
class Babylon::Metric
  class ArgumentError < ArgumentError; end

  def initialize name, category, amount
    @name = name
    @category = category
    @amount = amount
  end

  def self.call name:, category:, amount:
    new(name, category, amount).()
  end

  # What is it doing here exactly is it calling Counter or Gauge record method from here, 
  # based on valid method returns true or false?

  def call
    valid? ? record : notify
  rescue => e
    begin
      raise Babylon::Error, e.inspect
    rescue Babylon::Error => e
      Babylon::Event.(event: "babylon.error", error: e)
    end
  end

  def valid?
    # do validation
  end

  def notify
    # do some stuff 
  end

end
```

I think that the call method is able to in turn call Counter class and Gauge class record methods If the valid method returns true, But I don't know how it can call as these are protected members ?.

Comment: record method is called in parent, but defined in child - isn't scope chain moving upwards? You'd have to do something like Babylon::Metric::Counter.new.record in place of record I believe.

Comment: Edited the title - "members" isn't a term thats used in Ruby at all and will mostly just confuse Rubyists. In Ruby visibility only really applies to methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the parent class and call the `call` or `record` method on it, you will get a `NoMethodError` as you would expect. The trick is, that all of the methods of the parent are available in the children as well.

That means that if you initiate a child class and call `record` on it, the record method on the child class is called exactly as expected.

But also, if you call the `call` method on the child class, it will use the implementation from the parent, but in the context of the child class, meaning that the record method called in it, will be available and no error is raised.

Comment: But how can ```call``` method defined in ```Babylon::Metric``` class is able to call ```record``` method of ```Babylon::Metric::Counter``` or ```Babylon::Metric::Gauge``` class as ``` record ``` method is a protected member and cannot be accessed by parent class.

Comment: It's not the method defined in `Babylon::Metric` calling the method, it's an instance of the class `Babylon::Metric::Counter` calling the method. `Babylon::Metric::Counter` is a child of `Babylon::Metric` and it's instances have access to the `call` method defined in `Babylon::Metric` and also to the `record` method defined in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, `protected` methods can only be called with either:

- An implicit receiver (i.e. `say_hello` instead of e.g. `self.say_hello`)
- An explicit receiver in the same object family (self and descendants)

In the parent class, you can see that `record` is called with an implicit receiver, which means that the method can be either public, protected, *or* private.

For example:

```rb
class Foo
  def say_hello
    whisper_hello # implicit receiver
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  private # protected would work as well in this example

  def whisper_hello
    puts "(hello)"
  end
end
```

In this example, `Foo.new.say_hello` will fail because `whisper_hello` isn't defined in the parent class (in other words you could say that `Foo` is an abstract class); but `Bar.new.say_hello` will work just fine.

Comment: It should be noted though that `Object#send` and `Method#call` don't respect encapsulation and will let you call private and protected methods.

Comment: @max that's an advanced topic :)